# PHP Log in to show details

Tags: php

The website has a login system, however when a user logs into the website I simply want their details to appear on the next page. This is my code I so far. Problem is, I only want to display the logged in users details, not all the databases details.

```
<?php $servername = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = ""; $dbname = "loginsystem";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM members";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

LOG IN SYSTEM

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {

include_once("dbConnect.php");

// Set the posted data from the form into local variables
$usname = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$paswd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

$usname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $usname);
$paswd = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $paswd);

$sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM members WHERE username = '$usname' AND activated = '1' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$uid = $row[0];
$dbUsname = $row[1];
$dbPassword = $row[2];

// Check if the username and the password they entered was correct
if ($usname == $dbUsname && password_verify($paswd,$dbPassword)) {
    // Set session 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
    // Now direct to users feed
    header("Location: MemberDetails.php");
} else {
    echo "Oops that username or password combination was incorrect.
    <br /> Please try again.";
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: By the way, your code doesn't really match your question.

Comment: When you only want one dataset, why do you query the database to return all users? That somehow makes no sense.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback, i have edited the question. I have also added new answer which shows the log in system i am using. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
session_start();
```

to the top of the page and then on the next page as well and then you will be able to carry over those variables once they are set.

For example:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
```

Then on the next page call:

```
echo $_SESSION['user'];
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the fast response, I have added my code for the log in part of the website.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to implement the user login part. and after that, get the specified user id or login credentials and use that in your query.

In your LOG IN SYSTEM file, put `session_start();` before including the db connection.

Then in the member details page do this:

```
session_start(); //put this on the first line.
```

Then your query will now look like below:

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = ""; $dbname = "loginsystem";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];

$sql = "SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname FROM members WHERE user_id = ".$user_id;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "</td></tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Database structure

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for the fast respond, I have uploaded my log in system could you check see if its correct?. Thank you

Comment: I have updated my answer to take into account your code. That should work. Get back to me when you have implemented the answer

Comment: Hi, Ive already got session_start() added to the code. I am a little confused where you have "Then to run your query: $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];" where does that part come into play?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I've updated your entire code. The `$user_id = $_SESSION['id']` goes in somewhere there.

Comment: Hi thank you, I somehow have a Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_real_escape()

Comment: sorry, that should have been `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Updated now, just remove the call to that function.

Comment: Thank you

Another error - Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in on that line

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

I am so sorry for being a nuisance I am fairly new to PHP.

Comment: @WhitenaCording It's most likely because the session array is a string (taken from the POST username array) and not an integer. Therefore `WHERE user_id = ".$user_id;` needs to be changed to `WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- It still gives me the same Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLogInSystem\MemberDetails.php on line 182
0 results

On line 182 the code is - if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

Hope you can help guys

Comment: @WhitenaCording 182 lines; something else is causing this.

Comment: @WhitenaCording Plus, in one instance you're using `$dbCon` as the connection variable, and in another using `$conn` so one of them is wrong and is most likely why you're getting that error.

Comment: @WhitenaCording, I've seen where the error is coming from. It's this line:       `$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM members WHERE user_id = ".$user_id;`. Update it to this: `$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM members WHERE id = ".$user_id;`. I've updated it in my answer, too. It should work. The reason it wasn't working was the function was returning false, because of an unknown database column `user_id`, whereas the column in your table is `id`. Use the updated code, it should fix it.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer thanks again, still doesnt work for some reason got notice now - Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLogInSystem\MemberDetails.php on line 183
0 results

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi thanks for the response again, much appreciated, i cant see where i am using $dbcon ?

Comment: Do you have this line: `$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];` before your sql query? Just copy the entire code in my answer, should work.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer - yeah i still have this message, Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLogInSystem\MemberDetails.php on line 183
0 results

On that line the code is 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "</td></tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

Comment: can I see the structure of your database?

Comment: @WhitenaCording In your question `$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);` and `$usname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $usname);` etc.

Comment: @WhitenaCording So, where are we at?

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer Hi, yes i can provide information on my database structure, how would you like me to show you? Would it be ok to ask if you had a Skype account if you wouldnt mind helping me in the process. Thank you again for helping much appreciated.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi, well I had enough yesterday things just where not going to plan, ive just started looking at what you suggested so I will establish to see if this helps. Thank you once again.

Comment: @WhitenaCording, I thought maybe there was a way you could attach a screenshot of the db structure and point me to the URL. Anyway, if you feel Skype is preferable, here's my Skype ID: michael.o76

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer Hi thanks again, i have added you on skype, thank you

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer Hi, I have attached the image for the database structure as shown above. Thank you.

Comment: I think an issue maybe in my coding, as It is trying to get the rows, however i simply want to get the users details when they log into the system.

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["user_id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "</td></tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

Comment: @WhitenaCording, I see where your error is coming from now. Your database column name is `user_id` but you were using `id` in your queries. I have updated my answer to use `user_id`. Now, in your codes, where you have `id`, change them to `user_id`, which is what you have in your database. That is, wherever you have `SELECT id...` change it to `SELECT user_id...`. That should fix it.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer Hi, I already noticed the id was wrong yesterday, Its giving me an error on a different part of the code, on line 184, which the code is if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

Comment: if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

Comment: That is the code that's causing the error. But what is the error message?